# Docker PowerCLI exec user process caused "exec format error"

Tags: docker, powercli

I am trying to use powercli in docker to take a firmware backup of a host however I see the following error when running the docker run command

```
standard_init_linux.go:190: exec user process caused "exec format error"
```

I am running this with:

```
docker run --rm -it -v /home/user/DockerData/esx:/esx vmware/powerclicore /esx/backup2.ps1
```

The contents of backup2.ps1 are as follows

```
Set-PowerCLIConfiguration -InvalidCertificateAction Ignore -Confirm:$false | Out-Null
Set-PowerCLIConfiguration -Scope User -ParticipateInCEIP $false
$VI_SERVER = "192.168.1.1"
$VI_USERNAME = "backupuser"
$VI_PASSWORD = "password"
$FOLDER = "/esx/Backups/"
$DATE = Get-Date -f "dd-MM-yyyy"
Connect-VIServer -Server $VI_SERVER -User $VI_USERNAME -password $VI_PASSWORD | Out-Null
Get-VMHost | Get-VMHostFirmware -BackupConfiguration -DestinationPath $FOLDER
Rename-Item -Force $FOLDER/configBundle-$VI_SERVER.tgz -newName $FOLDER\$DATE--$VI_SERVER.tgz
Disconnect-VIServer * -Confirm:$false
```

I can run the docker container without the backup2.ps1, it runs, I can call the ps1 from within and it executes as it should - I am trying to roll it into a oneliner.

Docker host is running on ubuntu 18.04.  Have run dos2unix to check for rogue character returns.

Any ideas?

thankyou

Comment: Take a look at https://github.com/vmware/powerclicore - it has example (last snippet) which runs custom script. Pay attention to the `--entrypoint="/usr/bin/pwsh"` part of this line - it is crucial. With this option, `/usr/bin/pwsh /esx/backup2.ps1` will be executed instead of `/esx/backup2.ps1` (which gets executed in your case).

Comment: Thankyou - I was reading a comment on virtuallyGhetto that said you no longer needed to specify the entrypoint. I have since added and this is now working. Thankyou